# Scoped redirect when using Express.js Routers

Tags: redirect, express, routes

When using Express Routers, a route prefix can be provided:

```
var router = new Express.Router();
app.use("/scope", router);
```

Let us say that I have some CRUD routes in my Router.

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var result = create(req);
  res.redirect(result.id);
});

router.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
  var result = update(req);
  res.redirect(result.id);
});

router.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
  var result = findById(req.params.id);
  res.render("show.html", {data: result});
});
```

When requesting to the PUT above, the response is a redirect to "/scope/[id]" as it should be. When requesting to the POST, the response is a redirect to "/[id]" instead of the previous result.

I am not certain where to find the root of the issue, nor how to correct it.

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Comment: Two more questions: (1) Do you have `strict routing` enabled or disabled? and (2) can you should the code where the `POST` originates?

Comment: I am using Express 4.11.2 and have not changed strict routing from the default of 'disabled.' Though, since posting this question, I have made some changes around the form submission method and included the 'method-override' middleware.

The issue has been resolved within those changes. Unfortunately, I am working on a dirty branch and did not capture the problem state in version control, and am not inclined to manually dial back my changes until the problem appears again.

Comment: No worries. I will answer anyway bass on the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question anyway, for the benefit of anyone else who might encounter this issue.

What I suspect your original issue was that, since you had strict mode disabled (Express' default), your client side code was likely POSTing to `/scope' (which in non-strict node is the same as`/scope/`). Within your post handler you did a relative redirect using`res.redirect(result.id)`. Let say`result.id`is`123`, then a relative redirect would take you to`/123`.

> NOTE: Don't forget that Express has little to do with the actual redirects, which are taken care of client-side by the browser.

The issue could have easily been solved by ensuring your client side code POSTed to `/scope/`, after which a relative redirect to `id` would take you to `/scope/id`, just as you expected.